# How to use phantom Js to take screenshot of a website page at runtime?

Tags: java, phantomjs, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a website page at runtime, then upload it to s3.
I am trying to use PhantomJSDriverService.

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: why is phantomjs still used ? any special use case ?

Comment: Try to add, what you have done and ay what part you stuck, for getting fast answer, also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PDHide No. I don't know any other way to do so.

Comment: If you just need headless browser then al browsers including firefox edge chrome supports headless. PhantomJS deprecated